# Google colab always shows connecting, how can I solve it?

Tags: neural-network, connection, google-colaboratory, training-data

[This is the status of the problem in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdHjb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got a small workaround, here is the step:

- Close all your active Session & Clear your cookies
- Open a new collab session
- Switch the execution type to CPU and then get it back to GPU

Answer (score -4):

Based on my understanding, 'Connecting' can be due to many things. The most common reasons are

1. Your internet connection is unstable
2. You become idle* and the session was disconnected

*Either you are away from keyboard or you are doing something else instead of looking at the colab tab.

For 1, you can try using a different internet connection and see if that improves.

For 2, you can either move your mouse every now and then in the colab tab to prevent yourself from becoming idle.. or you can consider subscribing a premium version colab which help with that situation in theory.

Comment: Neither of these answers apply in my case.  I am trying to run a new session so I'm not idle, and have a stable connection, but Colab gets stuck "Connecting..." anyway.

Comment: By any chance your network provider blocks Colab? or you are under a firewall that does?